# GNUS Reuse Group Buffer When Opening Summary

Tags: emacs, gnus

I'm really enjoying using gnus as my mail reader, but I have one gripe. If I have a split (say I'm working on some code in the left buffer when gnus groups opened in the right) and open a summary buffer for my INBOX, it takes over the entire frame. Is there a setting somewhere to tell gnus to simply open the summary in the right-hand buffer so I can still see my code buffer on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `gnus-use-full-window` to `nil`, as mentioned in [the "Window Layout" section of the Gnus manual](http://gnus.org/manual/gnus_288.html).  Note the warning, though:

> Setting this variable to `nil' kinda works, but there are glitches.
>       Use at your own peril.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thanks. I'll heed the warnings in case anything funky starts to happen.